# Design patterns - Data to object

Tags: java, json, design-patterns, instance

Suppose I have some data in a file or maybe database. It could be JSON, XML, YAML, CSV, String[], etc.

I'd like to create a model object with this data. For example:

Data:

> ```
> {
>     "name": "John Doe",
>     "age": "30"
> }
> ```

Model (Pseudocode):

> ```
> class Person {
>     Person(name, age) {
>         this.name = name;
>         this.age = age;
>     }
>     // business logic
> }
> ```

Some code that creates Person objects from JSON data (Pseudocode):

> ```
> peopleArray = [];
> recordSet = aJSONReader.read('file');
> for (recordSet as r) {
>     peopleArray.add(new Person(r[0], r[1]));
> }
> ```

What would you use to build model objects from given data? In my example I'd start supporting JSON. What if I'd like to change it or support new data formats?
How do I decouple this code? Which design pattern fit here?

Answer (score 4):

Use the **strategy pattern** (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)). You want to provide different methods to parse data. A method would parse JSON, another method would parse XML and another method would read a database. Each method can be seen as a strategy to parse data and generate data objects.

Create a common interface, let's say `IDataObjectParser` with a single method like `public List<DataObject> parse()`. Each parser would implement this interface. Then you can exchange the parser whenever you want, e.g. during runtime or according to a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I like this technique. Create an abstract object who's responsibility will be to provide attributes. In this case `name` and `age`.

```
interface PersonInput {

    public String getName();

    public int getAge();
}
```

Have Person class use that object in the constructor

```
class Person {

    public Person(PersonInput input) {
        name = input.getName();
        age = input.getAge();
    }

}
```

Now you can have many implementations of PersonInput each dealing with different data format (CSV, XML, etc.)

JSON example:

```
class JsonPersonInput implements PersonInput {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public JsonPersonInput(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
        name = data.getString("name");
        age = data.getInt("age");

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

You use it like this

```
new Person(new JsonPersonInput(jsonString))
```

Comment: Interesting. Is it a some sort of design pattern?

Comment: Depends on your perspective, many design patterns are entangled in a particular solution. I would not stress over trying to find formal design patterns too much.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'data' you are referring to a persistence mechanism then this is the perfect situation for [Data Access Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (or DAOs).

This is most commonly associated with Java web applications and implementations for RDBMSs but it has applications in all Java applications requiring persistence.

You only need define a DAO interface for your person, say `PersonDAO` with two methods on it `getPerson()` and `savePerson()`.

```
interface PersonDAO {
    public Person readPerson(String path);
    public void addPerson(Person personToBeSaved);
}
```

Then create another class, say one for your JSON implementation, that implements your DAO, let's call ours JsonPersonDAO.

If you are using a factory to generate your Person objects you then only need to change the DAO implementation that you are using in a single place when the need arises. If you are generating your Person objects from inside your class you only need to change what DAO implementation it uses.

Further reading on this here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/dao.html